# UITableView like gridView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a NSMutableArray in which I m storing items taken from service url and done parsing.I m showing the array items in UITableView acting like gridview(4 columns in each row and no of rows depends on array count).It is something like showing all the online exam slots available in a week.So I have to load each day timings one by one and if all the slots are reserved for a particular day then should display a msg for that day (No slot available) and then load the next array items in a tableView. But I m able to get only the last day slots available.

I have to get in the following format:

```
10/1/2013

10:00 AM    11:00 AM   12:00 PM   1:00 PM
2:00 PM

11/1/2013

11:00 AM     12:00 PM   1:00 PM    2:00 PM 

12/1/2013

   No slot available

13/1/2013

10:00 AM    11:00 AM   12:00 PM   1:00 PM
2:00 PM     3:00 PM

............
```

As of now I m using a same tableview and loading each array items for a particular day seprately.But I m able to get only the last day timings

How can I get in this particular format?

Any suggestions/advices would be appreciable on which control to use or how to use the same tableView would be appreciable.

EDIT:

```
-(void)LoadWeekSlots
{

    for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
    {

      NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

        NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        [offsetComponents setDay:i];
        NSDate *nextDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate: [NSDate date] options:0];
        [offsetComponents release];
        [gregorian release];
        NSLog(@"%@",nextDate);

        NSDateFormatter *df=[[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init] autorelease];
        df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
        getdateinmmformat=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[df stringFromDate:nextDate]] componentsSeparatedByString:@""];
        NSLog(@"%@",getdateinmmformat);
        result=[[getdateinmmformat valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        weekdayString=[nextDate descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"%A" timeZone:nil locale:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]dictionaryRepresentation]];
        NSLog(@"Day :%@",weekdayString);
        selectedtableView=i;
        [self LoadSlots];
        NSLog(@"%@",arr1);
   }
}

-(void)LoadSlots{

// calling the service url and taking the values in NSMutableArray (arr1)
     [self CheckArray];

}


-(void)CheckArray{


    NSMutableArray *yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in arr3) {

        NSString *str=[dict valueForKey:@"Code"];

        NSString*newstr=  [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];

        [yourArray addObject:newstr];

    }

    BOOL isTheObjectThere = [yourArray containsObject:weekdayString];

    if([arr1 count]==0 && isTheObjectThere==YES)
    {

        displayError  =[[UILabel alloc]init];
        [displayError setFrame:CGRectMake(0,390,320,200)];
        displayError.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
        displayError.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        NSString *string1=@" No slot available.";
       displayError.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",string1];
       displayError.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
        displayError.shadowColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        displayError.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Italic" size:14];
        [testscroll addSubview:displayError];
       float fscrview =displayError.frame.origin.y + displayError.frame.size.height+ 60;
        testscroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, fscrview);

    }


    else
    {
      sections=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for(int s=0;s<1;s++)
          {
            NSMutableArray *section=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
             for(int i=0;i<[arr1 count];i++)
                {
                    Item *item=[[Item alloc] init];
                    NSString *eventName=[[arr1 objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"TimeStart"];

                    item.TimeStart=eventName;
                    [section addObject:item];

                }
                [sections addObject:section];

            }




            self.tableView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,390,320,[arr1 count]*40) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
            self.tableView.delegate = self;
            self.tableView.dataSource = self;
            self.tableView.scrollEnabled=NO;
            [testscroll addSubview:self.tableView];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
             self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.frame.origin.y, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.contentSize.height);
            float fscrview = self.tableView.frame.origin.y + self.tableView.frame.size.height + 10;
            testscroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, fscrview);
            testscroll.scrollEnabled=YES;
            }

        }

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableArray *sectionItems=[sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    int numRows=[sectionItems count]/4;
    if(numRows==0)
    {
        return 80;
    }

    else
    {

        NSArray* items = [sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        int total = [items count];
        float f = (float)total /4;
        int numberOfGridRows = ceilf(f);
        NSLog(@"\n\n Rows :>> %d",numberOfGridRows);
        if(numberOfGridRows==1)
        {
            return numberOfGridRows * 100.0;

        }

        else if(numberOfGridRows==2)
        {
            return numberOfGridRows * 70.0;

        }
        else if(numberOfGridRows==3)
        {
            return numberOfGridRows * 60.0;

        }
        else if(numberOfGridRows==4)
        {

            return numberOfGridRows * 70.0;

        }
        if(numberOfGridRows>4 && numberOfGridRows<8)
        {
             return numberOfGridRows * 65.0;


        }
        else
        {
          return numberOfGridRows * 40.0 ;
        }



    }
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *hlCellID=@"hlCellID";

    UITableViewCell* hlcell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:hlCellID];

    if(hlcell == nil)
    {
        hlcell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier:hlCellID]autorelease];

        hlcell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        hlcell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;    
    }
    int section=indexPath.section;
    NSMutableArray *sectionItems=[sections objectAtIndex:section];
    int n=[sectionItems count];
    int i=0,i1=0;
    while(i<n)
    {
        int yy= 4+i1*34;
        int j=0;
        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            if(i>=n)break;
           Item *item=[sectionItems objectAtIndex:i];
            CGRect rect=CGRectMake(0+70*j,yy,79,40);
            UIButton *button=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
            [button setFrame:rect];
            [button setContentMode:UIViewContentModeLeft];
            button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
            NSString *settitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",item.TimeStart];
            [button setTitle:settitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            NSString *tagValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d",indexPath.section+1,i];
            button.tag=[tagValue intValue];
            [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];     
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
           [hlcell.contentView addSubview:button];
            [button release];
            i++;




        }
        i1=i1+1;
    }
    return hlcell;

}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [sections count];
}
```

This is the code I have done .

Comment: Can you put some code you have written. So that we can try to rectify the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the some code from my this bellow code... remove some other code which not useful for you..

i had this type of requirement and i complete it with my bellow code and logic... also see the image i think you want something like that...

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [_grids count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    NSArray* items = [_grids objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    
    //number of rows in one grid if one row will have 4 items
    //    float totalRow = ceilf(items.count/4);
    int total = [items count];
    
    float f = (float)total /4;
    int numberOfGridRows = ceilf(f);
    NSLog(@"\n\n Rows :>> %d",numberOfGridRows);
    //height of table row
    return numberOfGridRows * 36.0 + 120;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Grid %d", section];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"gridCell";

    UITableViewCell *gridCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
    
    if(gridCell == nil)        
    {
        gridCell =  [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
        
        gridCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        
        gridCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        
    }
//    UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lion.jpg"]];
//    [img setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 120)];
//    [gridCell.contentView addSubview:img];
    
    UIImageView *imgUser = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"noImage.png"]];
    [imgUser setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 100, 115)];
    [gridCell.contentView addSubview:imgUser];
    
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    lbl.text = @"Dr. P.R. Joshi";
    lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:15];
    [lbl setFrame:CGRectMake(110, 5, 200, 31)];    
    [gridCell.contentView addSubview:lbl];

    UILabel *lblAddress = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    [lblAddress setFrame:CGRectMake(110, 31, 200, 31)];        
    lblAddress.text = @"706,Atlanta Tower,Gulbai Tekra,Ahemdabad-007.";
    lblAddress.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    lblAddress.numberOfLines = 0;
    lblAddress.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
//    CGSize sizeToMakeLabel = [lblAddress.text sizeWithFont:lblAddress.font]; 
    lblAddress.frame = CGRectMake(lblAddress.frame.origin.x, lblAddress.frame.origin.y, 
                             200,[self calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:lblAddress.text :lblAddress.font :200 :UILineBreakModeWordWrap] ); 

    lblAddress.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    [gridCell.contentView addSubview:lblAddress];
    
    DYRateView *rateView = [[[DYRateView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, lblAddress.frame.origin.y + lblAddress.frame.size.height + 5, 160, 14)] autorelease];
    rateView.rate = 4.5;
    rateView.alignment = RateViewAlignmentLeft;
    [gridCell.contentView addSubview:rateView];
    
    UIImageView *imgArrow = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"left-arrow-right-md.png"]];
    [imgArrow setFrame:CGRectMake(300, 57, 12, 18)];
    [gridCell.contentView addSubview:imgArrow];
    
    NSArray* items = [_grids  objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    
    int imageIndex = 0;
    
    int yOffset = 4;
    
    while (imageIndex < items.count)        
    {
        int yPos =  7 + yOffset * 30;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            CGRect  rect = CGRectMake((0 + i * 80), yPos, 80, 31);
            
            if (imageIndex < [items  count]) {
                
                UIImageView* imageView = [self gridImageRect:rect forImage:[items objectAtIndex:imageIndex]];
                
                [gridCell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
                [imageView release];
                
                UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                button.frame = rect;
                button.tag = imageIndex;
                [button addTarget:self 
                           action:@selector(btnTemp_Clicked:)
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
                
                [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title %d%d%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row,imageIndex] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12]];

//                [button.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
                [button setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle03.jpg"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];                
                [button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted ];
                
                [button setNeedsDisplay];
                
                [gridCell.contentView addSubview:button];
                
                //            rect = CGRectMake(((80 * i)-4), (yPos+44), 80, 12);
                //            
                //            
                //            
                //            UILabel* label = [self descriptionOfImage:imageIndex inRect:rect];
                //            
                //            [gridCell.contentView addSubview:label];
                //            
                //            [label release];
            }
            ++imageIndex;
        }
        ++yOffset;
    }
    return gridCell;
}

-(float) calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:(NSString*) text: (UIFont*)withFont: (float)width :(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
{
    [text retain];
    [withFont retain];
    CGSize suggestedSize = [text sizeWithFont:withFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:lineBreakMode];
    
    [text release];
    [withFont release];
    
    return suggestedSize.height;
}

-(IBAction)btnTemp_Clicked:(id)sender{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@"Selected Image : %d  Button Title is ==>> %@",btn.tag,btn.titleLabel.text);
}

-(UIImageView *)gridImageRect:(CGRect)rect  forImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    imageView.image = image;
    
    return imageView;
}

-(UILabel *)descriptionOfImage:(int)imageNumber inRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image  %d", imageNumber + 1];
    
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:12];
    
    return label;
}
```

See the screen shot which output of this code...

[image]  [image]

Also See these bellow **links** for `UIGridView` Demo and tutorials..

1. [UIGridView](https://github.com/tanin47/UIGridView)
2. [GMGridView](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView#readme)

   i hope this helpful to you...

Comment: Hi Paras,
Im wondering what's the point in copy pasting all your code here. Including your logic and everything. Which actually can confused the users.

Comment: I agree it's always better to provide everything you have. So user can decide what to take and what to not. But I think @arizah has managed to show the table view. He is actually struggling with the logic i fee. At that time if you provide such a long code. I don't understand the point. I appreciate you have also given screenshots which will help him. But I don't agree on you pasting all your code in cellForRowAtIndexPath, calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth, btnTemp_Clicked, gridImageRect, descriptionOfImage etc..

Comment: but what he exactly want dude??

Comment: @ParasJoshi what he want we need to ask him. But Im damn sure he doesn't want calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth, btnTemp_Clicked, gridImageRect, descriptionOfImage :p

Comment: @Rushi oh ok dude if i understand what arizh exactly want then i remove that post dude.. thank you.. :)

Comment: What I exactly want the same like paras said with modifications.I want to know whether the grids u showed in screen shots be displayed one below the other?

Comment: @arizah then here you want to edit this above code by me?? means remove some code .. or stay there if its useful for you...

Comment: But in my requirement see I can/cannot have slots on a particular day.If slots are available then must be displayed in tableview otherwise should display a message and check for other day

Comment: @Paras can u please come to chat discussion

Comment: yes  dude but chat link not appear now , but when appear i sure come on chat and sorry for late reply bcoz i am busy now with some work so dude.. but i will give answer or suggesion sure dude.. and also i not understand whole problem but i will try it...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22499/discussion-between-arizah-and-paras-joshi)

Comment: Paras I got it partially but I have a doubt. I have a string as one of the object in my array and Im comparing it like this  BOOL isstring= [tableViewarray containsObject:@"Not available"];But I m getting error .How should I compare?

Answer (score 1):

First off you are better of using [UICollectionView](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12) for representing Grids instead of `UITableView`. Its lot cleaner.

Next, in your specific case since you are trying to show 4 grids in 1 row, you need to use modulo `%` operator in `cellForRow` delegate in `UItableView`. also adjust the number of items in uitableview delegate to (totalitems)/4. I bet there are a few more things which I forgot to mention.

I would strongly suggest you take time to migrate to `UICollectionView` its cleaner...

Answer (score 1):

i think this http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/nrgridview--2 will help you

Regards
Saad